# html2canvas not working properly in angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to create an image and then convert the image to pdf using jsPDF all this inside an angular app, however when i try to render the HTML what i get is an image with the background of the page.

the code i'm using to render the page is this:

```
  function downloadPDF(){
    html2canvas(document.body, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
      },
      logging: true
    });
```

this code is inside the controller of my view

This is my view:
[image]

This is what i get
[image]

I get this in the console

```
html2canvas: Preload starts: finding background-images
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Preload: Finding images
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Preload: Done.
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 1 / 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 2 / 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 3 / 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 4 / 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: start: images: 5 / 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 Finished loading images: # 5 (failed: 0)
html2canvas.min.js:7 html2canvas: Renderer: Canvas renderer done - returning canvas obj
```

Have any idea if there's an incompatibility of the library with angular or if i'm doing something wrong.

Thanks for the help

Comment: could we see pictures?

Comment: @phenxd i just added the pictures

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: Also try a bunch of console.log() to make sure you DO have the right elements

Comment: i don't get any errors in the console, and i've just added the info i get from the console